# OpenLayers 4 static new layers disappear when changing projection from Mercator to Ortho

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers

Hi have a map showing vector layers with a projection WGS84 (EPSG:4326) (it is online at [this link](https://www.marinemammalhabitat.org/imma-eatlas/), so you can test it). By clicking the button "Projection" (right side of the screen) a new View is created with a an orthographic projection. Everything works, until I had to load new layers that should be rendered all the time (they are somewhat static as the ocean base map): these are the darker blue areas. These layers disappear completely when I change projection. The code applied, working for all the other layers, is the following:

```
//fill pattern for regions NYAA (not yet assessed)
   var fillNYAA =
    new ol.style.Style({
     fill: new ol.style.Fill({
     color: [43, 43, 91,0.5]
   }),
   stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
   color: [43, 43, 91,0.5],
   width: 1
 })
});
//**************************//
//SET ORTHO PROJECTION
//**************************//
 proj4.defs(
 "ORTHO-SOUTH",
 "+proj=ortho +lat_0=-90 +lon_0=15 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs "
 );
 ol.proj.get('ORTHO-SOUTH').setExtent([-6370997, -6370997, 6370997, 6370997]);
```

The following function (testXHR) was created following [these suggestions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/364552/openlayers-4-6-5-geojson-wgs84-not-mapped-with-a-different-projection)

```
 /* function to get featureProjection on response status=200*/
 function testXHR (extent, resolution, projection) {
  var source = this;
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', source.getUrl());
  xhr.onload = function() {
   if (xhr.status == 200) {
     var features =
     source.getFormat().readFeatures(xhr.responseText, {
      dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
      featureProjection: projection,
     });
     features.forEach(function(feature){
     if (feature.getGeometry().intersectsExtent(projection.getExtent())) {
      source.addFeature(feature);
      }
     });
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
 }
```

The new layers are 8 and this is a sample code for one of these

```
 var source_region_south_east_tropical_temperate_pacific =
  new ol.source.Vector({
   format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
   loader: testXHR,
   url: url_child + '/wp-content/themes/mmpatf/maps/resources   /nyaa_region_south_east_tropical_temperate_pacific_ocean.geojson',
   attributions: [
    new ol.Attribution({
     html: 'NYAA South East Tropical and Temperate Pacific Ocean'
     })
   ]
  }); 
  //set layer
  var layer_region_south_east_tropical_temperate_pacific =
    new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: source_region_south_east_tropical_temperate_pacific,
    style: fillNYAA,
    name: 'NYAA South East Tropical and Temperate Pacific Ocean',
    visible: true,
  });
```

The sources are then grouped together

```
    source_nyaa = [];
     source_nyaa.push (
      source_region_arctic,
      source_region_east_atlantic,
      source_region_north_pacific,
      source_region_north_west_atlantic,
      source_region_south_east_atlantic,
      source_region_south_east_tropical_temperate_pacific,
      source_region_south_west_atlantic,
      source_region_wider_caribbean);
```

Likewise all the other layers, the new ones are loaded on the map

```
     map.addLayer(ocean_map);
     map.addLayer(layer_region_south_east_tropical_temperate_pacific);
     //follow all the other layers...
```

The script for changing projection when clicking the button is as follows (again it works for all the layers except these new named NYAA)

```
     var circle = new ol.geom.Circle([0, 0], 6370997);
      var style = new ol.style.Style({
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: "black"
      })
     });
     var createCircle = function(e) {
      var vectorContext = e.vectorContext;
      e.context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
      vectorContext.setStyle(style);
      vectorContext.drawCircle(circle);
      e.context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
     }
    var viewProjSelect = document.getElementById('view-projection');

    function updateViewProjection() {
     var newProj = viewProjSelect.value;

    if(newProj && newProj=="ORTHO-SOUTH") {
    var newView = new ol.View({
    projection: newProj,
    center: [0,-90],
    //   center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-97.6114, 38.8403], viewProjection),
    zoom: 2,
    minZoom: 1
    });
    map.setView(newView);
        map
        .getLayers()
        .getArray()[0]
        .on('postcompose', createCircle);   
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i< source_group.length; ++i) {
            source_group[i].clear();
        }
        var j;
        for (j = 0; j< source_aoi.length; ++j) {
            source_aoi[j].clear();
        }
        var k;
        for (k = 0; k< source_nyaa.length; ++k) {
            source_nyaa[k].clear();
        }              
              document.getElementById('species-sidebar-container').style.display = 'none';
              document.getElementById('criteria-sidebar-container').style.display = 'none';
              document.getElementById('imma-sidebar-container').style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        var newView = new ol.View({
        projection: newProj,
        center: [0,0],
        //   center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-97.6114, 38.8403], viewProjection),
        zoom: 2,
        minZoom: 1
        });
        map
            .getLayers()
            .getArray()[0]
            .un('postcompose', createCircle);
        map.setView(newView);

        var i;
        for (i = 0; i< source_group.length; ++i) {
            source_group[i].clear();
        }
        var j;
        for (j = 0; j< source_aoi.length; ++j) {
            source_aoi[j].clear();
        } 
        var k;
        for (k = 0; k< source_nyaa.length; ++k) {
            source_nyaa[k].clear();
        }  
        
        document.getElementById('species-sidebar-container').style.display = 'inherit';
        document.getElementById('criteria-sidebar-container').style.display = 'inherit';
        document.getElementById('imma-sidebar-container').style.display = 'inherit';  
    }

  };
```

Could you please give me some piece of advice? Am I missing something?

Comment: Possibly due to invalid geometries in the Ortho projection if they cross the equator - there is a partial fix for that in OpenLayers 6 https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/11175

Comment: Thanks Mike, do you have any suggestion on how to implement the patch in OpenLayers 4?

Comment: I don't think it would help in this case as all the nyaa polygons are either north of the equator or cross it, so all would have some invalid coordinates in the Ortho projection.  You could use a utility such as turf.js https://turfjs.org/ to find the difference between your polygons and one covering the northern hemisphere (or intersection with one covering the southern hemisphere) then reprojecting the results to ortho should be valid.

Comment: Thanks @Mike, however it is strange to me as also the other layers that are correctly projected in Ortho do cross the equator and don't show any problem. I will give a look into turf.js